# R, String Match or String match combination of strings

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have Set of Strings like "United Kingdom","United States","China","India",
And Other String Has to be compared with the set of above strings,And can be combination of multiple values of the set of above strings seperated by "|" .

Like Example:

```
String1 <- "China"
String2 <- "United States|China"
String3 <- "United States|India|China"
SetoFStrings <- c("United Kingdom","United States","China","India")
```

So in all Case When Compared String1,String2,String3 with SetofStrings,The Result value has to be true. How can this be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `any` with `grepl`

```
any(grepl(String1, SetoFStrings))
#[1] TRUE
any(grepl(String2, SetoFStrings))
#[1] TRUE
any(grepl(String3, SetoFStrings))
#[1] TRUE
```

If the objective is to create the 'String's as in the input post

```
sapply(dat2$Strings, function(pat) any(grepl(pat, SetoFStrings)))
```

#### data

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c('China', 'UnitedStates', 'India'), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
dat2 <- data.frame(Strings =  Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep="|"), 
           dat1$Col1, accumulate = TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: and how can it be taken forward, String1,String2,String3 in a column of a dataframe,The whole column should be compared with SetoFStrings ?
Using Apply Function ?

Comment: @Shivpe_R  It is not clear from the comments.  Can you update your quesion and the expected output

Comment: @Shivpe_R  Perhaps `any(grepl(paste(unique(as.character(yourdata$Col)), collapse="|"), SetoFStrings))`

Comment: I have a column in dataframe, Which conatins values like String1,String2,String3 till Some 200 Values, And each value in the column should be comapred with SetoFStrings, So expecting a column after comparing with SetoFStrings,Like 

    TRUE
    TRUE
    FALSE
    . and so on

Comment: @Shivpe_R  Do you have the same `SetoFStrings` to be compared ?

Comment: Yes SetoFstrings is constant

Comment: @Shivpe_R  UPdated the post